# XML? JSON? Archiving HTML content into individual files for searching from SQL Server

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

I've got records from a table in SQL Server containing both int, char, and text fields. The text fields have HTML in them.

I'd like to archive these for searching into individual flat files. I'm not sure whether to go XML or JSON.

My hesitance to go XML is that the HTML fields will be escaped, and I'd like to search them with PowerGrep to get data between certain custom tags embedded in the text field.

Should I just go with XML and search for the escaped codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've done this with columns containing HTML code in the past, I've always exported as delimited txt, with something rare as row and column delimiters (due to having non-English language (eg Japanese) characters in there, although this can be difficult).
I've used Ø (alt+157) and ø (alt+155) in the past.

But maybe this is too simple for what you need?

Comment: That sounds promising, but how do you handle embedded CRLFs?

Comment: I've left the CRLFs in, it makes the HTML code easier to read after all. I use ø for a field delimiter and Ø for a row delimiter.